# Creating tables in django

Tags: django, datatables

I'm using Django CMS for an application. I want to create 4 different tables; each of one with 6 columns and some rows. I want to insert data from the interface and not in the code, for instance table1, columns are:

```
Author, Title of Book, Student using the book and Date.
```

I want to insert the information from web interface and I'd like to add rows again from interface so number of rows is not fixed.

Do you know how I can do that?

Thank you

Comment: are you using https://www.django-cms.org/ ? Sounds like a simple django app would be sufficient - but we would need quite some more information about your models, and what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Yes, I'm using django CMS. I don't know how to create the tables in the model but most important I want to add information not from the code but from web interface. If I have to use an app, what app do you suggest?

Comment: you will probably not find a prebuilt django app that suits your needs, so you will need to build up your models.py, add those to the admin with admin.py, etc...that will require some basic understanding of django and python. good start, if you haven't seen that yet: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/